# Is the longtable enviroment limited? I have a several pages long table

Tags: tables, longtable

I am writing a long table with several complex things inside. When I realized I needed a multiple page table I tried to change `table` to `longtable`, but it just gives me a lot of errors.

How can I achieve to get a multiple page table?

code with normal table:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,final]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\usepackage{listings}
\colorlet{listingscolor}{black!15}
\lstnewenvironment{mylistings}
  {\lstset{language=C++,
    backgroundcolor=\color{listingscolor}, % set backgroundcolor
    basicstyle=\footnotesize,% basic font setting
    }%
  }
  {}

\lstnewenvironment{cpptable}
  {\lstset{language=C++,
    basicstyle=\footnotesize,% basic font setting
    }%
  }
  {}


\begin{document}


\begin{table}[H]
\caption{C++ DIC class public functions.}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{>{\columncolor{listingscolor}}l c c c}
\toprule[0.2em]

\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Function in C++} }& \textbf{Input} & \textbf{Output} & \shortstack{\textbf{Document} \\ \textbf{corresponding chapter} }\\
\hline
\midrule
\multicolumn{4}{c}{Main setup and API functions. Public functions.}\\
\hline
\begin{cpptable}
 getF() 
\end{cpptable}
 &
   \begin{minipage}{1.5in}
    \vspace{4pt}
    \begin{itemize}
   \item Subset center
   \vspace{-10pt}
   \item window size
   \end{itemize}
   \end{minipage}
   \vspace{4pt}
  &   
   \begin{minipage}{1.5in}
    \vspace{4pt}
    \begin{itemize}
   \item Undeformed \\image subset
   \end{itemize}
   \end{minipage}
   \vspace{4pt}

    & \ref{sec:basic principles},\ref{sec:sub-pixel}\\
  \hline


  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\label{tab:DIC class private}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

What I have tried:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,final]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\usepackage{listings}
\colorlet{listingscolor}{black!15}
\lstnewenvironment{mylistings}
  {\lstset{language=C++,
    backgroundcolor=\color{listingscolor}, % set backgroundcolor
    basicstyle=\footnotesize,% basic font setting
    }%
  }
  {}

\lstnewenvironment{cpptable}
  {\lstset{language=C++,
    basicstyle=\footnotesize,% basic font setting
    }%
  }
  {}


\begin{document}


\begin{longtable}[H]
\caption{C++ DIC class public functions.}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{>{\columncolor{listingscolor}}l c c c}
\toprule[0.2em]

\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Function in C++} }& \textbf{Input} & \textbf{Output} & \shortstack{\textbf{Document} \\ \textbf{corresponding chapter} }\\
\hline
\midrule
\multicolumn{4}{c}{Main setup and API functions. Public functions.}\\
\hline
\begin{cpptable}
 getF() 
\end{cpptable}
 &
   \begin{minipage}{1.5in}
    \vspace{4pt}
    \begin{itemize}
   \item Subset center
   \vspace{-10pt}
   \item window size
   \end{itemize}
   \end{minipage}
   \vspace{4pt}
  &   
   \begin{minipage}{1.5in}
    \vspace{4pt}
    \begin{itemize}
   \item Undeformed \\image subset
   \end{itemize}
   \end{minipage}
   \vspace{4pt}

    & \ref{sec:basic principles},\ref{sec:sub-pixel}\\
  \hline


  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\label{tab:DIC class private}
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: A `longtable` environment shouldn't be used inside a `table` environment.

Comment: @egreg I actually tried to replace table by longtable, as in a example I found in the web

Comment: Please replace `table` and `tabular` with `longtable` in the way you tried. It will be easier to help you in finding what's wrong.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ? Is there something wrong with my question??

Comment: @AnderBiguri Don't worry! David is rightly proud of his own creature.

Comment: @AnderBiguri it was a comment on the _question_ (the title:-) (but I deleted the comment anyway)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something more like this (although it is still too wide for the page)

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,final]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{longtable,booktabs}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\usepackage{listings}
\colorlet{listingscolor}{black!15}
\lstnewenvironment{mylistings}
  {\lstset{language=C++,
    backgroundcolor=\color{listingscolor}, % set backgroundcolor
    basicstyle=\footnotesize,% basic font setting
    }%
  }
  {}

\lstnewenvironment{cpptable}
  {\lstset{language=C++,
    basicstyle=\footnotesize,% basic font setting
    }%
  }
  {}


\begin{document}

\small
\begin{longtable}{>{\columncolor{listingscolor}}l c c c}
\caption{C++ DIC class public functions.\label{tab:DIC class private}}\\

\toprule[0.2em]

\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Function in C++} }& \textbf{Input} & \textbf{Output} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
Document \\corresponding\\ chapter\end{tabular}}\\
\hline
\midrule
\multicolumn{4}{c}{Main setup and API functions. Public functions.}\\
\hline
\begin{cpptable}
 getF() 
\end{cpptable}
 &
   \begin{minipage}{1.5in}
    \vspace{4pt}
    \begin{itemize}
   \item Subset center
   \vspace{-10pt}
   \item window size
   \end{itemize}
   \end{minipage}
   \vspace{4pt}
  &   
   \begin{minipage}{1.5in}
    \vspace{4pt}
    \begin{itemize}
   \item Undeformed \\image subset
   \end{itemize}
   \end{minipage}
   \vspace{4pt}

    & \ref{sec:basic principles},\ref{sec:sub-pixel}\\
  \hline


  \bottomrule



\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The problem with the width is something appart, ill try to solve it later. Thank you for the answer

Comment: Damn I didnt know the package was yours, thats why you where surprised! haha

Comment: @AnderBiguri :-)

Comment: @My miktex compiler doesnt seem to find the longtable package... I cant find it using the package manager...How can I manually instal it?  Are you sure you created it? :D

Comment: @AnderBiguri It is part of the required core latex distribution, either it is there or whoever gave you latex broke the latex licence conditions.

Comment: Yup I found it. Stil when I add the \usepackage{longtable} header Texmaker starts the process but never ends it... I manually installed latex in my computer, dont think I broke any license conditions!

Comment: @AnderBiguri I only mentioned that as you would not expect to see longtable in an optional package in the package manager as it is a required part of latex. Sorry I can't help with the miktex configuration I have not used it.

Comment: But still, your solution doesnt seem to compile...

Comment: @AnderBiguri I do test my answers:-) I added an image. "doesnt seem to compile" isn't really any information what error do you get?

Comment: The problem is that doesnt seem to compile... There are no errors, Texmaker just start the process of compilation and stays there forever. I guess that there is no problem with the longtable enviroment if i use somewhere else in the doc usual tables, or if i have a listoftables, right?

Comment: It seems that I have some problem with my whole document with longtable. In the aisled test there is no problmem with it. Ill open a new question.

Comment: Lets continue this conversation here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119678/longtable-usepackage-problem , i think i found whats wrong....

Answer (score 6):

A `longtable` environment makes the table, so it shouldn't have a `tabular` inside it. Here's how you can do; check with the package manual for other adjustments.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,final]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs,longtable}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\usepackage{listings}
\colorlet{listingscolor}{black!15}
\lstnewenvironment{mylistings}
  {\lstset{language=C++,
    backgroundcolor=\color{listingscolor}, % set backgroundcolor
    basicstyle=\footnotesize,% basic font setting
    }%
  }
  {}

\lstnewenvironment{cpptable}
  {\lstset{language=C++,
    basicstyle=\footnotesize,% basic font setting
    }%
  }
  {}


\begin{document}


\begin{longtable}{>{\columncolor{listingscolor}}l c c c}
% Here starts the first header
\caption{C++ DIC class public functions.}\label{tab:DIC class private}\\
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Function in C++} }&
  \textbf{Input} &
  \textbf{Output} &
  \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}\textbf{Document} \\ \textbf{corresponding chapter}\end{tabular}\\
\midrule
\multicolumn{4}{c}{Main setup and API functions. Public functions.}\\
\midrule
\endfirsthead

% Here starts the header specification for the following pages
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Function in C++} }&
  \textbf{Input} &
  \textbf{Output} &
  \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}\textbf{Document} \\ \textbf{corresponding chapter}\end{tabular}\\
\midrule
\multicolumn{4}{c}{Main setup and API functions. Public functions.}\\
\midrule
\endhead

% now the table contents

\begin{cpptable}
 getF() 
\end{cpptable}
 &
   \begin{minipage}{1.5in}
    \vspace{4pt}
    \begin{itemize}
   \item Subset center
   \vspace{-10pt}
   \item window size
   \end{itemize}
   \end{minipage}
   \vspace{4pt}
  &   
   \begin{minipage}{1.5in}
    \vspace{4pt}
    \begin{itemize}
   \item Undeformed \\image subset
   \end{itemize}
   \end{minipage}
   \vspace{4pt}

    & \ref{sec:basic principles},\ref{sec:sub-pixel}\\
  \midrule
\begin{cpptable}
 getF() 
\end{cpptable}
 &
   \begin{minipage}{1.5in}
    \vspace{4pt}
    \begin{itemize}
   \item Subset center
   \vspace{-10pt}
   \item window size
   \end{itemize}
   \end{minipage}
   \vspace{4pt}
  &   
   \begin{minipage}{1.5in}
    \vspace{4pt}
    \begin{itemize}
   \item Undeformed \\image subset
   \end{itemize}
   \end{minipage}
   \vspace{4pt}

    & \ref{sec:basic principles},\ref{sec:sub-pixel}\\
  \midrule
\begin{cpptable}
 getF() 
\end{cpptable}
 &
   \begin{minipage}{1.5in}
    \vspace{4pt}
    \begin{itemize}
   \item Subset center
   \vspace{-10pt}
   \item window size
   \end{itemize}
   \end{minipage}
   \vspace{4pt}
  &   
   \begin{minipage}{1.5in}
    \vspace{4pt}
    \begin{itemize}
   \item Undeformed \\image subset
   \end{itemize}
   \end{minipage}
   \vspace{4pt}

    & \ref{sec:basic principles},\ref{sec:sub-pixel}\\
  \midrule
\begin{cpptable}
 getF() 
\end{cpptable}
 &
   \begin{minipage}{1.5in}
    \vspace{4pt}
    \begin{itemize}
   \item Subset center
   \vspace{-10pt}
   \item window size
   \end{itemize}
   \end{minipage}
   \vspace{4pt}
  &   
   \begin{minipage}{1.5in}
    \vspace{4pt}
    \begin{itemize}
   \item Undeformed \\image subset
   \end{itemize}
   \end{minipage}
   \vspace{4pt}

    & \ref{sec:basic principles},\ref{sec:sub-pixel}\\
  \midrule
\begin{cpptable}
 getF() 
\end{cpptable}
 &
   \begin{minipage}{1.5in}
    \vspace{4pt}
    \begin{itemize}
   \item Subset center
   \vspace{-10pt}
   \item window size
   \end{itemize}
   \end{minipage}
   \vspace{4pt}
  &   
   \begin{minipage}{1.5in}
    \vspace{4pt}
    \begin{itemize}
   \item Undeformed \\image subset
   \end{itemize}
   \end{minipage}
   \vspace{4pt}

    & \ref{sec:basic principles},\ref{sec:sub-pixel}\\
  \midrule
\begin{cpptable}
 getF() 
\end{cpptable}
 &
   \begin{minipage}{1.5in}
    \vspace{4pt}
    \begin{itemize}
   \item Subset center
   \vspace{-10pt}
   \item window size
   \end{itemize}
   \end{minipage}
   \vspace{4pt}
  &   
   \begin{minipage}{1.5in}
    \vspace{4pt}
    \begin{itemize}
   \item Undeformed \\image subset
   \end{itemize}
   \end{minipage}
   \vspace{4pt}

    & \ref{sec:basic principles},\ref{sec:sub-pixel}\\
  \midrule
\begin{cpptable}
 getF() 
\end{cpptable}
 &
   \begin{minipage}{1.5in}
    \vspace{4pt}
    \begin{itemize}
   \item Subset center
   \vspace{-10pt}
   \item window size
   \end{itemize}
   \end{minipage}
   \vspace{4pt}
  &   
   \begin{minipage}{1.5in}
    \vspace{4pt}
    \begin{itemize}
   \item Undeformed \\image subset
   \end{itemize}
   \end{minipage}
   \vspace{4pt}

    & \ref{sec:basic principles},\ref{sec:sub-pixel}\\
  \midrule
\begin{cpptable}
 getF() 
\end{cpptable}
 &
   \begin{minipage}{1.5in}
    \vspace{4pt}
    \begin{itemize}
   \item Subset center
   \vspace{-10pt}
   \item window size
   \end{itemize}
   \end{minipage}
   \vspace{4pt}
  &   
   \begin{minipage}{1.5in}
    \vspace{4pt}
    \begin{itemize}
   \item Undeformed \\image subset
   \end{itemize}
   \end{minipage}
   \vspace{4pt}

    & \ref{sec:basic principles},\ref{sec:sub-pixel}\\
  \midrule
\begin{cpptable}
 getF() 
\end{cpptable}
 &
   \begin{minipage}{1.5in}
    \vspace{4pt}
    \begin{itemize}
   \item Subset center
   \vspace{-10pt}
   \item window size
   \end{itemize}
   \end{minipage}
   \vspace{4pt}
  &   
   \begin{minipage}{1.5in}
    \vspace{4pt}
    \begin{itemize}
   \item Undeformed \\image subset
   \end{itemize}
   \end{minipage}
   \vspace{4pt}

    & \ref{sec:basic principles},\ref{sec:sub-pixel}\\
  \midrule
\begin{cpptable}
 getF() 
\end{cpptable}
 &
   \begin{minipage}{1.5in}
    \vspace{4pt}
    \begin{itemize}
   \item Subset center
   \vspace{-10pt}
   \item window size
   \end{itemize}
   \end{minipage}
   \vspace{4pt}
  &   
   \begin{minipage}{1.5in}
    \vspace{4pt}
    \begin{itemize}
   \item Undeformed \\image subset
   \end{itemize}
   \end{minipage}
   \vspace{4pt}

    & \ref{sec:basic principles},\ref{sec:sub-pixel}\\
  \midrule
\begin{cpptable}
 getF() 
\end{cpptable}
 &
   \begin{minipage}{1.5in}
    \vspace{4pt}
    \begin{itemize}
   \item Subset center
   \vspace{-10pt}
   \item window size
   \end{itemize}
   \end{minipage}
   \vspace{4pt}
  &   
   \begin{minipage}{1.5in}
    \vspace{4pt}
    \begin{itemize}
   \item Undeformed \\image subset
   \end{itemize}
   \end{minipage}
   \vspace{4pt}

    & \ref{sec:basic principles},\ref{sec:sub-pixel}\\
  \midrule
\begin{cpptable}
 getF() 
\end{cpptable}
 &
   \begin{minipage}{1.5in}
    \vspace{4pt}
    \begin{itemize}
   \item Subset center
   \vspace{-10pt}
   \item window size
   \end{itemize}
   \end{minipage}
   \vspace{4pt}
  &   
   \begin{minipage}{1.5in}
    \vspace{4pt}
    \begin{itemize}
   \item Undeformed \\image subset
   \end{itemize}
   \end{minipage}
   \vspace{4pt}

    & \ref{sec:basic principles},\ref{sec:sub-pixel}\\
  \midrule
\begin{cpptable}
 getF() 
\end{cpptable}
 &
   \begin{minipage}{1.5in}
    \vspace{4pt}
    \begin{itemize}
   \item Subset center
   \vspace{-10pt}
   \item window size
   \end{itemize}
   \end{minipage}
   \vspace{4pt}
  &   
   \begin{minipage}{1.5in}
    \vspace{4pt}
    \begin{itemize}
   \item Undeformed \\image subset
   \end{itemize}
   \end{minipage}
   \vspace{4pt}

    & \ref{sec:basic principles},\ref{sec:sub-pixel}\\
  \midrule
\begin{cpptable}
 getF() 
\end{cpptable}
 &
   \begin{minipage}{1.5in}
    \vspace{4pt}
    \begin{itemize}
   \item Subset center
   \vspace{-10pt}
   \item window size
   \end{itemize}
   \end{minipage}
   \vspace{4pt}
  &   
   \begin{minipage}{1.5in}
    \vspace{4pt}
    \begin{itemize}
   \item Undeformed \\image subset
   \end{itemize}
   \end{minipage}
   \vspace{4pt}

    & \ref{sec:basic principles},\ref{sec:sub-pixel}\\
  \midrule
\begin{cpptable}
 getF() 
\end{cpptable}
 &
   \begin{minipage}{1.5in}
    \vspace{4pt}
    \begin{itemize}
   \item Subset center
   \vspace{-10pt}
   \item window size
   \end{itemize}
   \end{minipage}
   \vspace{4pt}
  &   
   \begin{minipage}{1.5in}
    \vspace{4pt}
    \begin{itemize}
   \item Undeformed \\image subset
   \end{itemize}
   \end{minipage}
   \vspace{4pt}

    & \ref{sec:basic principles},\ref{sec:sub-pixel}\\
  \midrule
\begin{cpptable}
 getF() 
\end{cpptable}
 &
   \begin{minipage}{1.5in}
    \vspace{4pt}
    \begin{itemize}
   \item Subset center
   \vspace{-10pt}
   \item window size
   \end{itemize}
   \end{minipage}
   \vspace{4pt}
  &   
   \begin{minipage}{1.5in}
    \vspace{4pt}
    \begin{itemize}
   \item Undeformed \\image subset
   \end{itemize}
   \end{minipage}
   \vspace{4pt}

    & \ref{sec:basic principles},\ref{sec:sub-pixel}\\
  \midrule
\begin{cpptable}
 getF() 
\end{cpptable}
 &
   \begin{minipage}{1.5in}
    \vspace{4pt}
    \begin{itemize}
   \item Subset center
   \vspace{-10pt}
   \item window size
   \end{itemize}
   \end{minipage}
   \vspace{4pt}
  &   
   \begin{minipage}{1.5in}
    \vspace{4pt}
    \begin{itemize}
   \item Undeformed \\image subset
   \end{itemize}
   \end{minipage}
   \vspace{4pt}

    & \ref{sec:basic principles},\ref{sec:sub-pixel}\\
  \midrule
\begin{cpptable}
 getF() 
\end{cpptable}
 &
   \begin{minipage}{1.5in}
    \vspace{4pt}
    \begin{itemize}
   \item Subset center
   \vspace{-10pt}
   \item window size
   \end{itemize}
   \end{minipage}
   \vspace{4pt}
  &   
   \begin{minipage}{1.5in}
    \vspace{4pt}
    \begin{itemize}
   \item Undeformed \\image subset
   \end{itemize}
   \end{minipage}
   \vspace{4pt}

    & \ref{sec:basic principles},\ref{sec:sub-pixel}\\
  \midrule
\begin{cpptable}
 getF() 
\end{cpptable}
 &
   \begin{minipage}{1.5in}
    \vspace{4pt}
    \begin{itemize}
   \item Subset center
   \vspace{-10pt}
   \item window size
   \end{itemize}
   \end{minipage}
   \vspace{4pt}
  &   
   \begin{minipage}{1.5in}
    \vspace{4pt}
    \begin{itemize}
   \item Undeformed \\image subset
   \end{itemize}
   \end{minipage}
   \vspace{4pt}

    & \ref{sec:basic principles},\ref{sec:sub-pixel}\\
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Same than the other answer... I cant compile this solution! dont knwo why....

Comment: @AnderBiguri Neither do I: I just copied the example I made and that compiles flawlessly on my machine. Can you be more explicit about what goes wrong?

Comment: It seems that I have some problem with my whole document with longtable. In the aisled test there is no problmem with it. Ill open a new question.